# Hi How do i workout this mysql query question

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

List the course number, the offering number, and the average GPA of students enrolled. Only include courses offered in winter term in which the average GPA of enrolled students is greater than 3.0.
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVAgd.png)

Here is the database, if you need anything else let me know
I have tried this but can't seem to get anywhere

```
SELECT O.CourseNo, E.offerNo, S.StdGPA
FROM Offering O JOIN 
Student S JOIN
Enrollment E
WHERE O.OfferNo = E.OfferNo
AND E.stdSSN = S.StdSSN
AND O.OffTerm = "WINTER"
AND S.StdGPA > 3.0;
```

Comment: What problem are you specifically having? What doesn't work the way it should? Are columns case sensitive (I can never remember), in which case is it `E.offerNo` or `E.OfferNo`?

Comment: I think it will be better if you list the data that you're using. Then explain from that data the results you are expecting, and what results you are getting instead. Right now you're asking other people to create this data on their own. Also please see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952). And edit your Question to include all information. Don't use comments for additional clarifications.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to state Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'E.StdSSN' in 'where clause'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this query.

```
SELECT O.CourseNo, E.offerNo, S.StdGPA FROM Offering O INNER JOIN Enrollment E
ON O.OfferNo = E.OfferNo INNER JOIN Student S
ON E.stdSSN = S.StdSSN WHERE O.OffTerm = "WINTER" AND S.StdGPA > 3
```